# Libstreaming errors (decoder buffer not big enough, decoder did not decode anything)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, rtsp, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to use the libstreaming library from here: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

I'm following example2 from this: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples

Trying to use this streaming library on a Galaxy Nexus.

If I use a small resolution (new VideoQuality(128,96,20,500000)), I get an error that the decoder did not decode anything:

```
06-09 19:59:31.531: D/libEGL(8198): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:59:31.539: D/libEGL(8198): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:59:31.539: D/libEGL(8198): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:59:31.632: D/OpenGLRenderer(8198): Enabling debug mode 0
06-09 19:59:33.773: D/MainActivity(8198): Start
06-09 19:59:33.773: D/MainActivity(8198): Found mSurfaceView: net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView{420285e0 V.E..... ........ 32,32-688,910 #7f080001 app:id/surface}
06-09 19:59:33.789: I/dalvikvm(8198): Could not find method android.media.MediaCodec.createInputSurface, referenced from method net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.encodeWithMediaCodecMethod2
06-09 19:59:33.789: W/dalvikvm(8198): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 377: Landroid/media/MediaCodec;.createInputSurface ()Landroid/view/Surface;
06-09 19:59:33.789: D/dalvikvm(8198): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x005e
06-09 19:59:33.789: I/MediaStream(8198): Phone supports the MediaCoded API
06-09 19:59:33.843: D/dalvikvm(8198): GC_CONCURRENT freed 65K, 2% free 9075K/9168K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 34ms
06-09 19:59:33.843: D/dalvikvm(8198): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
06-09 19:59:34.750: V/VideoQuality(8198): Supported resolutions: 1920x1080, 1280x720, 960x720, 800x480, 720x576, 720x480, 768x576, 640x480, 320x240, 352x288, 240x160, 176x144, 128x96
06-09 19:59:34.750: V/VideoQuality(8198): Supported frame rates: 15-15fps, 15-30fps, 24-30fps
06-09 19:59:35.140: I/OMXClient(8198): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:59:35.171: I/OMXClient(8198): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:59:35.179: I/OMXClient(8198): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:59:35.211: I/OMXClient(8198): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:59:35.242: W/ACodec(8198): Use baseline profile instead of 8 for AVC recording
06-09 19:59:35.242: I/ACodec(8198): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
06-09 19:59:35.515: I/OMXClient(8198): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:59:35.515: E/OMXNodeInstance(8198): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
06-09 19:59:36.359: D/dalvikvm(8198): GC_CONCURRENT freed 156K, 3% free 9356K/9552K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 25ms
06-09 19:59:38.531: W/System.err(8198): java.lang.RuntimeException: The decoder did not decode anything.
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.decode(EncoderDebugger.java:799)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.debug(EncoderDebugger.java:246)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.debug(EncoderDebugger.java:115)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.testMediaCodecAPI(H264Stream.java:132)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.testH264(H264Stream.java:119)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.configure(H264Stream.java:111)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session.syncConfigure(Session.java:395)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session$3.run(Session.java:371)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-09 19:59:38.539: W/System.err(8198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 19:59:38.546: W/System.err(8198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 19:59:38.546: W/System.err(8198):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

If I try with a bigger resolution (new VideoQuality(640,480,20,500000)), it complains that the decoder input buffer is not big enough:

```
06-09 19:51:51.054: D/libEGL(8096): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:51:51.062: D/libEGL(8096): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:51:51.070: D/libEGL(8096): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-09 19:51:51.164: D/OpenGLRenderer(8096): Enabling debug mode 0
06-09 19:51:53.054: D/MainActivity(8096): Start
06-09 19:51:53.054: D/MainActivity(8096): Found mSurfaceView: net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView{42031b00 V.E..... ........ 32,32-688,910 #7f080001 app:id/surface}
06-09 19:51:53.062: I/dalvikvm(8096): Could not find method android.media.MediaCodec.createInputSurface, referenced from method net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.encodeWithMediaCodecMethod2
06-09 19:51:53.062: W/dalvikvm(8096): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 377: Landroid/media/MediaCodec;.createInputSurface ()Landroid/view/Surface;
06-09 19:51:53.062: D/dalvikvm(8096): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x005e
06-09 19:51:53.070: I/MediaStream(8096): Phone supports the MediaCoded API
06-09 19:51:53.132: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 2% free 9038K/9168K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 42ms
06-09 19:51:53.132: D/dalvikvm(8096): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
06-09 19:51:54.039: V/VideoQuality(8096): Supported resolutions: 1920x1080, 1280x720, 960x720, 800x480, 720x576, 720x480, 768x576, 640x480, 320x240, 352x288, 240x160, 176x144, 128x96
06-09 19:51:54.039: V/VideoQuality(8096): Supported frame rates: 15-15fps, 15-30fps, 24-30fps
06-09 19:51:54.468: I/OMXClient(8096): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:51:54.500: I/OMXClient(8096): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:51:54.515: I/OMXClient(8096): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:51:54.554: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 106K, 2% free 9210K/9344K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-09 19:51:54.554: I/dalvikvm-heap(8096): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.458MB for 460816-byte allocation
06-09 19:51:54.578: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 9660K/9796K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
06-09 19:51:54.593: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 9660K/9796K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 20ms
06-09 19:51:54.656: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 9660K/9796K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-09 19:51:54.656: I/dalvikvm-heap(8096): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.897MB for 460816-byte allocation
06-09 19:51:54.671: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 10110K/10248K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-09 19:51:54.679: I/OMXClient(8096): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:51:54.687: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 10110K/10248K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
06-09 19:51:54.703: W/ACodec(8096): Use baseline profile instead of 8 for AVC recording
06-09 19:51:54.703: I/ACodec(8096): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
06-09 19:51:55.257: D/dalvikvm(8096): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 1% free 10501K/10576K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 32ms
06-09 19:51:55.359: I/OMXClient(8096): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-09 19:51:55.359: E/OMXNodeInstance(8096): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The decoder input buffer is not big enough (nal=91280, capacity=65536).
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.check(EncoderDebugger.java:838)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.decode(EncoderDebugger.java:753)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.debug(EncoderDebugger.java:246)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.hw.EncoderDebugger.debug(EncoderDebugger.java:115)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.testMediaCodecAPI(H264Stream.java:132)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.testH264(H264Stream.java:119)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H264Stream.configure(H264Stream.java:111)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session.syncConfigure(Session.java:395)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session$3.run(Session.java:371)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 19:51:56.187: W/System.err(8096):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I've tried dozens of different combinations for resolution, framerate, and bitrate. Everything I try results in either "The decoder did not decode anything" or "The decoder input buffer is not big enough."

Does anyone have this library working out of the box? What are the causes of these errors and what are the solutions? If my search results are any indication, I seem to be the only person in the world having this problem. I appreciate any insight!

Here is the code from my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.cornet.cornetspydroid2;

import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.SessionBuilder;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.audio.AudioQuality;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoQuality;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Session.Callback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String ip = "10.3.1.204";
    private static final VideoQuality VIDEO_QUALITY = new VideoQuality(128,96,20,500000);

    private Session mSession;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }

    public void start(View view) {

        if (mSession != null && mSession.isStreaming()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Already streaming!");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Start");

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);

        mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setCallback(this)
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
            .setPreviewOrientation(90)
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(16000, 32000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setVideoQuality(VIDEO_QUALITY)
            .setDestination(ip)
        .build();

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

        if (!mSession.isStreaming()) {
            mSession.configure();
        }

    }

    public void stop(View view) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Stop");

        if (mSession != null) {
            mSession.stop();
        }

        if (mSurfaceView != null) {
            mSurfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (mSession != null) {
            mSession.release();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewStarted() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Preview started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionConfigured() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Preview configured.");
        // Once the stream is configured, you can get a SDP formated session description
        // that you can send to the receiver of the stream.
        // For example, to receive the stream in VLC, store the session description in a .sdp file
        // and open it with VLC while streming.
        Log.d(TAG, mSession.getSessionDescription());
        mSession.start();
    }

    @Override
        public void onSessionStarted() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Session started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitrareUpdate(long bitrate) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Bitrate: "+bitrate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionError(int message, int streamType, Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStopped() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Session stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSession.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSession.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE: The MediaStream class in this library has a static initializer that looks for a class with the name "android.media.MediaCodec". When I force it to use sSuggestedMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API instead of the MediaCodec, there are no errors, regardless of the resolution I choose, and Wireshark sees packets flowing from the phone. But VLC cannot play this video stream for some reason (udp/h264://@10.3.1.204:16420). This seems to indicate that the resolution I choose is not the problem; at least not directly.

The errors are occurring in the Session.syncConfigure() call (it's not even getting to Session.start()). It is able to configure the audio stream successfully, but the call to Stream.configure() for the video stream is failing. The syncConfigure() call eventually makes its way to H264Stream.testMediaCodecAPI(), which makes a call to EncoderDebugger.debug(). That debug() method is throwing the two original errors: input buffer not big enough, or decoder did not decode anything.

Something that may be revealing (included in the original logs I provided): I always seem to be getting a debug error from the "dalvikm" tag on startup: "Could not find method android.media.MediaCodec.createInputSurface, referenced from method net.majorkernalpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.encodeWithMediaCodecMethod2". Immediately after that log entry, there is a warning, again from the "dalvikm" tag: "VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 377: Landroid/media/MediaCodec;.createInputSurface ()Landroid/view/Surface;" Could this have anything to do with it? Why is it able to find the MediaCodec class from the Class.forName() call in MediaStream, but yet later when it tries to access a documented method from MediaCodec (createInputSurface), there are warnings that it can't find that method?? My AndroidManifest.xml files (in the main project and the libstreaming library project) both specify min SDK 16 and target SDK 19. The MediaCodec class was added in API version 16 so I should not be getting these warnings. Does this indicate that I'm mis-configured somehow? Could these warnings be related to the problem I'm having?

Answer (score 4):

**Actually the createInputSurface() is not mandatory to use libstreaming, it is only needed when using the mode MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2.** **Lisbtreaming is supposed to work on Android 4.1 and 4.2, as long as the MediaCodec API is working properly on the phone.**

**Explanation:**

When using libstreaming on Android 4.1 and 4.2 you will indeed see the VM complains in the logs that the createInputSurface() does not exist. That won't make the app crash since this method won't ever get called (unless you try to force MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2 somehow).

**Now let me explain how the "The decoder input buffer is not big enough" error can happen.**

When libstreaming is used with the MODE_MEDIACODEC_API with a resolution that has never been used before on the user's phone it first tries to see if at least one encoder accessible through the MediaCodec API is working properly at that resolution. To do that, it will try to encode and decode a simple video using every encoder and decoder available on the phone. The bug you are mentioning happens when a decoder has not been able to decode the H264 stream produced by an encoder.

If that test stops and no valid encoder/decoder pair has been found, the resolution is considered not supported on the phone. Libstreaming will then try to fallback on the MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API mode.

*To find out what those "modes" actually are, just read the [main page](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) of the project, I explained all this in greater lengths there.*

**Important thing to know about that test**

The result of that test is stored in the SharedPreference, so if you want to retry you can clear the cache of your app or change the boolean DEBUG to true in EncoderDebugger.java. Also, if the version of android changes (after an update for example) the test will be run again.

**The reason behind this test is that the MediaCodec API is buggy as hell, if you have tried to use it, you probably know that already.**

(This test is actually written in the EncoderDebugger class, you can check it out on github.)

**So what happened on the OP's phone?**

Well, his phone do not pass the test with Android 4.2, but it does with android 4.3. The MediaCodec API has been patched on that phone in-between.

There may still be a way to improve that test to make it work on the Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2 though. For example, it currently only supports the following color formats:

- COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar
- COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar
- COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
- COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
- COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:

*(Disclaimer, I wrote the lib)*

Comment: If you only test decider/encoder loop but not the camera, then some devices will misbehave, like Galaxy Nexus which lies about supported resolutions, and silently ignores setParameters() when the settings are not to it's liking.

Comment: Hello @fyhertz, thank you for your wonderful work. However, I have the same problem with Google Glass, which technically are Android 4.4: the MediaCodec test is failing at high resolutions. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy Nexus has problems with its reported supported video resolutions. I never tried 128x96, and I don't have access the the phone anymore to check it. I did try 320x240, and it is broken on this device. But 640x480 does work, but it may be unhappy about 20 FPS. I suggest that you try 15 FPS:

```
private static final VideoQuality VIDEO_QUALITY = VideoQuality(640, 480, 15, 500000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried (640, 480, 15, 500000) - "The decoder input buffer is not big enough." This page suggests 800000 bps for 640 x 480: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/dynstream_live/popup.html. Same error with 800000 bps. I even backed that down to 50 bps; same error: "The decoder input buffer is not big enough." =(

Comment: I tried it with .setPreviewOrientation(0) instead of (90), which shows the preview sideways instead of right-side-up, but it still errors out with "The decoder input buffer is not big enough." I added android:screenOrientation="landscape" to my MainActivity element in the manifest, but it had no affect. So I added setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in MainActivity.onCreate(). That put my app in landscape mode, but it still throws the same error: "The decoder input buffer is not big enough" (with both 0 and 90 preview orientations). Thanks again for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem! My Galaxy Nexus has Android 4.2.2. While the MediaCodec class exists in 4.2.2, the createInputSurface() method was not added until 4.3 (build 18). I tested it with a 4.3 device and it works.

Don't use this library for 4.1.x or 4.2.x devices unless you force sSuggestedMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API in the MediaStream static initializer.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience :

```
private static final VideoQuality VIDEO_QUALITY = VideoQuality(352, 288, 30, 300000);
```

Works great with no issues.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that VideoQuality. Same problem. "The decoder did not decode anything." What phone model did you try this on? A Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: Yes, And use the media_codec_api_1.
Make sure to uninstall the app so the media codec check will run for the first time.

Comment: I uninstalled the app and tried again, with the resolution you specified. "The decoder did not decode anything." I can't force it to use encodeWithMediaCodecMethod1() instead of method2() (I assume that's what you mean) because it doesn't make it that far. Those methods are called by MediaStream.start(), but it fails on the call to H264Stream.configure(), before start() even has a chance. I updated the original question with these details.

Comment: setStreamingMethod(MediaStream.MODE_MEDIACODEC_API)

Does this works for you?